# Searching in Array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following jQuery and I'm confused as to why it's returning `-1` and not 0 ? Is anyone able to explain:

```
var one = $('.test');
var two = $('.test2');

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(one);

if($.inArray($('.test'), myArray) < 0) {
   myArray.push(two);         
}

console.log($.inArray($('.test'), myArray)); //return -1
```

I setup http://jsfiddle.net/ecrMw/1/ and I'm trying to return `0` for `$('.test')` ? That is, find it in the array ?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to test `console.log($.inArray(one, myArray));` which does return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the jQuery object is actually a **collection** not a DOM element. What you're looking for is the facsimile of:

```
var one = $('.test')[0];
var two = $('.test2')[0];

// on with your code
```

Then you'd test again against the **element**:

```
if ($.inArray($('.test')[0], myArray)){
}
```

otherwise (notated bluntly) you're adding arrays to an array:

```
var one = $('.test'); // actually a [$] array
var two = $('.test2'); // actually another [$] array

var myArray = []; // empty array
myArray.push(one); // one = [[$]];
```

Then comparing if an array is within another array becomes a more complex issue.

Comment: thanks brad. I'm trying to add a bunch of elements to an array and then search across all elements added to the array ? I did try `[0]` but that doesn't search across everything in the array ?

Comment: @Andy: So why aren't you using `.find()`, `.has()` or `.is()`?

Comment: Unclear how I could use those to search across values added to `myArray` ?

Comment: @Andy: I guess the question is this: What are you trying to accomplish? Given that jQuery objects and how you're approaching it isn't working, what's the original problem and I'll see if I can't find a better solution. ;-)

Comment: Sure :) I'm adding multiple `[$]` to `myArray` which can contain multiple classes i.e. [$('.test'), $('.test12')]. Then all I'm basically trying to do - if the element is already in the array, ignore otherwise add.

Comment: @Andy: So step back a second. Why not just use: `var classes = []; classes.push('test1'); if (!$.inArray('test2',classes)){ classes.push('test2'); }` then you can turn it in to a query (either as an "AND" (`$('.'+classes.join('.'))`) or "OR" (`$('.'+classes.join(',.'))`) type match)

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = $('.test');

console.log($('.test') == one); //Outputs false
```

Javascript does not know how to compare the two objects therefore their comparison returns false.  I am guessing that its looking at the memory address to determine their equality.

Since js cannot determine their equality, I'm guessing the jquery library does not handle objects in the inArray() method.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fB44M/) fiddle ,I have re-wrote it

e.g

```
 var found = $('.test,.test2').map(function(){return $(this).get(0)})

  var foundAry=$.makeArray(found);

  console.log($.inArray($('.test').get(0), foundAry));
```

The point is that you need to search for DOM object in array not for JQUERY object in array.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why use an array? You could use a jQuery collection.

```
var $one = $('.test'),
    $two = $('.test2'),
    $myCollection = $();

$.merge( $myCollection, $one );

if( $myCollection.index( $one ) < 0) {
   $.merge( $myCollection, $two );  
}

console.log( $myCollection.index( $one )  ); //returns 0
```